# How do I write an XML using a custom XSD schema?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

This might be very simple, but for the life of me I haven't been able to figure it out. I am new to schema's so that's definitely part of my issue.

I have a C# program that pulls tables from a database and adds these tables to a data table and then a data set. From there, I am using the WriteXml(fileName) to generate the XML. I have been able to create an XSD from the generated XML, and then made some changes based on how I'd like the XML output to look.

How can I use the custom XSD I have created to properly format an XML? Any libraries, or any sort of suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using to write the xml.

```
public static void WriteXml(string filePath, string projectType)
    {
        List<string> tableNames = GetAllTableNames();
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
            
            SqlConnection con;
            SqlDataAdapter sda;
            DataTable dt;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(projectType);

            using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                foreach (string table in tableNames)
                {
                    using (var cmd_selectAllFromTable = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd_selectAllFromTable.Connection = con;
                        cmd_selectAllFromTable.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd_selectAllFromTable.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
                        dt = new DataTable(table);
                        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_selectAllFromTable);
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            ds.WriteXml(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Below is the Schema. I have included how the first element would look, and more elements would follow. What I want is for the XML I generate to follow the XSD (below) and create the elements in order I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="Program">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Project">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Field3" type="xs:dateTime" />
                  <xs:element name="Field4" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Field5" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Field6" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Field7" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSD defines the structural rules for validating an XML document, it doesn't define how it gets formatted. Formatting is usually done using XSLT.

(You can write schema-aware XSLT code, which can help with optimisation and debugging, but most people don't).